# Aggregate data based on a specific time range

Tags: r

Suppose that we have a timestamps column and a value column and we want to aggregate the value column according to 15 or 20 minutes time interval. How would you do it in R? The following is a sample to prepare the data.

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-06-01")
interval <- 1 # 1 minute interval
end <- start + as.difftime(1, units="days")
timestamps = as.numeric(seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end))
values = rnorm(length(timestamps))
dt = data.frame(timestamps,values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `xts` package when you deal with time series objects:

```
library(xts)
xx <- xts(values,order.by = timestamps)
## aggregate by mean/sum
period.apply(xx,endpoints(xx,'minutes',15),mean)
```

where `timestamps`

```
timestamps = seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end)
```

Comment: There is problem with this method. If data is separated with a 20 min interval, it still creates 3 entries for an hour. While we know that for an hour, if we aggregate the data using 15 minutes interval, one of the intervals should be zero.

Comment: well, try the above code with interval=20. You'll see that rather than 4 entries for each hour (according to our 15-minutes aggregation), we receive 3 entries. For instance, starting from 12:00, we have to have entries for 12:00,12:15,12:30,12:45. However, with 20 minutes interval, we only get entries like this 12:00, 12:20, 12:40.